# In uncertainty principle of waves

Tags: waves, electromagnetic-radiation, wavefunction, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

In uncertainty relations between freq. and time, if you had a part of a wave but not the entire cycle,(thus it is said that the frequency/wavelength is uncertain) couldn’t you based on the short curve you have determine how the wave will continue, with angles and derivatives? And through that know exactly both time, frequency, wavelength, energy exactly?

If you can't do the above described, why? Is it not possible to determine how a wave will continue based on a part, at least the coming cycle? The cycle the short curve is a part of? I understand than other later cycles might be different when it is not a pure sine wave, but I feel that you should be able to determine the one cycle the curve is a part of. **If this isn't possible, why and can a single curve like that on the picture correlate with many frequencies?**

Comment: Please do not vandalize your own posts by editing all content out of them. If you want to delete a post, click the delete button. Note that you cannot delete a question that has at least one upvoted answer, since deleting the question would delete the answer, too, and it would be unfair to the answerer to delete their positively-scored contribution along with yours.

Answer (score 4):

> Is it not possible to determine how a wave will continue based on a part [of the] cycle?

No, not in general. Because any/every function can be represented as a Fourier series, *e.g.,* https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1378633/

So, in particular, your waveform could look like a cosine wave (roughly what you seem to have drawn) for some fraction (or even multiple) of $2\pi$, and then look like anything after that. There'd always exist some coefficients (and phases) $a_n,b_n$ such that a Fourier series roughly of the form $f(t)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n\sin(nt+\theta_n)+b_n\cos(nt+\phi_n)$ will reproduce it to any desired accuracy.